# rust detect global shortcut

Tags: rust, keyboard

I want to implement that when I press `cmd + c` (or other customize shortcuts for other functions) 3 times on a text in chrome webpage, my background rust process will detect that and do something,

I tried crossterm, but that depends on terminal

Comment: This requires you to directly talk to the keyboard driver. Windows itself will only ever direct keystrokes to the active window, for security reasons. Implementing something like this might trigger antivirus programs though, because it's similar behavior to keyloggers.

Comment: @Finomnis note that the `cmd + …` shortcut hints at MacOS rather than Windows. But the rest of your remark should apply in MacOS too.

Comment: @Jmb My oversight. But yes, it most likely applies for MacOS as well.

Comment: have you tried to find a crate on the internet before asking here?

Comment: @alexzander yes, I found crate for window, but no crate for both MacOs and Windows, I can only implement this by looping check what i have pressed now, but this cause higher CPU occupy

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to write a browser extension that listens for keypresses and then writes to a local pipe or sends a request to a local port where your Rust program is listening.